# Linear function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write a piecewise function that can take a percentage from 95 to 65 and convert that to a gpa value. The trick is, 95=4.0,  94=3.9, 93=3.8, 92=3.7, and that continues decreasing by .1 per percentage point until it hits 65=1.0. I'm becoming stumped how to code this without manually entering in a ton of else-ifs.

```
$("#theButton").click(function() {
    var perc = $("#perc").val();
    var hardperc = (1+((perc-65)/10));
    perc = parseFloat(perc);
```

Comment: Hey pijoborde. We'd love to help, but in order for us to do so, we'll need to see your code. Generally speaking, your question will be received somewhat poorly if you haven't shared an attempt of your own before asking for help. To clean up your question and *add* the missing code to it, click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53178510/edit) button.

Comment: Hello Pijoborde! Welcome to SO! Please show us what you have tried so far and we'll help you from there.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted, and read [ask]

Comment: You dont need logic for it. Just math. Give a try with a math eyes.

Comment: @pijoborde: Note that to show your code, you can click the `edit` link under your question.  You can simply add additional information there, including something about what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want simple linear normalization then the following function should do the trick. Rather than use repeated logic or conditionals, you can just use some math.

```js
//Reusable Linear Normalization function
const linearNormalize = (fromMin, fromMax, toMin, toMax) => value => {
  //Normalize the input value
  var pct = (value - fromMin) / (fromMax - fromMin);
  var normalized = pct * (toMax - toMin) + toMin;

  //Cap output to min/max
  if (normalized > toMax) return toMax;
  if (normalized < toMin) return toMin;
  return normalized;
}

//Wrapper function with your specific inputs
const gradeToGpa = linearNormalize(65, 95, 1.0, 4.0);

console.log(gradeToGpa(78));
```

With [Scott Sauyet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet)'s [curried functions](https://fr.umio.us/favoring-curry/) suggestion:

```js
const linearNormalize = (fromMin, fromMax, toMin, toMax) => value => {
  var pct = (value - fromMin) / (fromMax - fromMin);
  var normalized = pct * (toMax - toMin) + toMin;

  if (normalized > toMax) return toMax;
  if (normalized < toMin) return toMin;
  return normalized;
}

const gradeToGpa = linearNormalize(65, 95, 1.0, 4.0);

console.log(gradeToGpa(78));
```

Comment: I'd suggest a better signature is `linearNormalize = (fromMin, fromMax, toMin, toMax) => value => { /* ... */ }`.  Then you can simply write, `gradeToGpa = linearNormalize(65, 95, 1.0, 4.0)`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I often find myself conflicted on the use of curried functions. On one hand, they leave signatures concise and neat. On the other, passing the arguments along without showing the hand-off sometimes feels like I'm sacrificing clarity for brevity.

Comment: @TylerRoper: I'm a [big proponent](https://fr.umio.us/favoring-curry/) of currying.  It's not for every situation, but I find it much more often clarifying than obscuring, especially by avoiding the complexities of naming.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Just wanted to loop back around and say that I got a chance to read the post you'd mentioned in your last comment. Very well written and super informative. I appreciate you taking the time to write that and I've certainly learned a thing or two about currying :)

Comment: @TylerRoper: Thank you.  I'm glad you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

This should help. You'll need to account for incorrect values such as above 95 and below 65 but this should get you started.

```
function gpa(input){
  var thescore = (1 + ((input - 65) / 10)).toFixed(2);
    return thescore;
}

alert(gpa(94));
```

**Output:** 3.90

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d7x8qb40/

Comment: Thank you for the help!